# Convert HHH:MM:SS to seconds

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, datetime, sql-server-2012

From the source database, I am getting HH:MM:SS as 832:24:12

Currently I am using below statement which is working fine for most of the cases hh:mm:ss but it fails when hours are more than 99

```
ISNULL(LEFT(COLUMN,2) * 3600  + RIGHT(LEFT(COLUMN,5),2) * 60 + RIGHT(COLUMN, 2) ,0)
```

Comment: [Column] is varchar which usually comes as 23:34:12 (i.e. HH:MM:SS) but in some cases hours exceeds and it comes as 832:24:12

Comment: It is not null but in HH:MM:SS, hour value is > 24 so I am not able to use above statement or any date function.

Comment: I have just use below statement don't know if it is correct (SUBSTRING(COLUMN,0,(CHARINDEX(':',COLUMN,0)))*3600)+(LEFT(RIGHT(COLUMN,5),2)*60)+RIGHT(COLUMN,2)

Comment: So your column value is `832:24:12`, what would your expected output be? (And in what datatype?)

Comment: in above case, 832 is hours, 24 is minute and 12 is second. Output should be an integer 832*3600+ 24*60+12

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just another option with a small tweak to your original

**Example**

```
Declare @V varchar(50) = '832:24:12'

Select (left(@V,charindex(':',@V)-1)*3600) + (left(right(@V,5),2)*60) + right(@v,2)
```

**Returns**

```
2996652
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a tricky solution using [**PARSENAME()**](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/using-the-parsename-function-to-split-delimited-data) function.

```
DECALRE @Hours INT = 0, @Minutes INT = 0 , @Seconds INT = 0

SELECT @Hours =  PARSENAME(REPLACE('832:24:12'+':00', ':', '.'),4),
       @Minutes = PARSENAME(REPLACE('832:24:12'+':00', ':', '.'),3),
       @Seconds = PARSENAME(REPLACE('832:24:12'+':00', ':', '.'),2)

SELECT @Hours * 3600  + @Minutes * 60 + @Seconds as TotalSeconds
```

I am replacing ':' with '.' character after appending dummy sequence of characters ':00' for PARSENAME() function to work by splitting into delimitted data.

For table query

```
SELECT   PARSENAME(REPLACE(ISNULL(ColumnName + ':00',0), ':', '.'),4) * 3600 +
         PARSENAME(REPLACE(ISNULL(ColumnName + ':00',0), ':', '.'),3) * 60 +
         PARSENAME(REPLACE(ISNULL(ColumnName + ':00',0), ':', '.'),2) As TotalSecs
FROM TableName
```

Answer (score 1):

This of a guess, however...

```
CREATE TABLE #Test (TimeString varchar(10))
INSERT INTO #Test
VALUES ('832:24:12')

SELECT TimeString,
       (LEFT(TimeString, H.CI - 1) * 3600) + (SUBSTRING(TimeString,H.CI +1, M.CI - H.CI -1) * 60) + (RIGHT(TimeString, LEN(TimeString) - M.CI))
FROM #Test T
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES(CHARINDEX(':',TimeString))) H(CI)
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES(CHARINDEX(':',TimeString, H.CI+1))) M(CI);

DROP TABLE #Test;
```

Answer (score 0):

Hours can be the leftwards chars minus 6 positions to take into account the positions for minutes and seconds in the string (:##:##).
The minutes can accessed by taking the left 2, of the rightmost 5 chars.
The seconds are the right 2 chars.

Ex:

```
DECLARE @tempval varchar(100) = '832:24:12'

SELECT LEFT(@tempval, LEN(@tempval) - 6) * 3600
      +LEFT(RIGHT(@tempval, 5), 2) * 60
      +RIGHT(@tempval, 2)
```

Returns

```
2996652
```